# Wrongfully accused of lending my security badge to another employee

Tags: united-states, human-resources, security

I work in the cybersecurity division of my employer, in a lead role for close to 9 years.

Two days ago, I was working late patching and monitoring our systems as a result of a security incident that came out over the weekend. I also just happened to forget my regular access badge at home, that had elevated access to all securied areas,  so had to get a temporary access badge programmed with **access to sensitive building areas that only security team folks have access to , such as the server rooms.**

When I left on Monday, the front desk reception people had already left. Having there being no one to check in my badge and almost no other folks at office, I left my temp badge at reception (which in hindsight is bad)
I did not want to be accused of not returning company equipment so did not bring badge home that day with me.

Apparently someone else took the temp badge I returned before reception could check it in and reset the associated physical access. Yesterday, the new borrower of the temp badge returned it, having used it. **The problem though, is the badge still shows in the system as having me as the registered / authorized user, not the new borrower.**

Today, I got an unpleasant email from security divusion management , cc' my manager and HR, falsely assuming I had lent my temporary badge to this other person. Lending of / deliberate misuse of access credentials is strictly disallowed by company policy and can be reason for summary dismissal. **Even worse, due to role in security division, expectations to follow policy is higher than for non info security folks**

**Addenum**

After review of electronic badge system access logs, I now know the identity of the person who took the access badge. I am also now able to definitively say the other person did not access any areas he was not authorized to access using my credentials. Finally, server room access logs and security cameras footage did not show unauthorized access to the room.

**Update**: How this turned out was I got a formal warning and my company believed it was indeed accidental , caused by confusion rather than malice. My proactiveness in reviewing logs and surveillance cameras helped my defense. So far , there has been no demotion or other job consequences outside of formal warning.

**How do I minimize damage as a result of the false accusation?**

**I also see a system weakness in that expectations are unclear in return of badges during non working hours. Should this issue be raised when I respond?**

Comment: What does existing policy say you _should_ have done with the temporary pass? (You say it's ‘unclear’… If policy could be read to say that you should take the pass home, then why were you worried about getting into trouble for that? Or if it seem to allow for leaving it at reception, what did you do wrong? Or if it says something else, why didn't you do that?)

Comment: Is there security camera footage of reception, showing you leaving the pass there?

Comment: I'd also give a strong advice to the front desk and physical security part of the building: A secure drop box for guest passes. When I worked at a bank, guests needed to deposit their guest pass in a receptacle to activate the single-person rotating door when they left.

Comment: @Gidds, nothing at all, silence. Policy states each employee must wear their badge when working, cannot loan their badges to anyone, and must get a temporary badge if they dont have their permanent badge for some reason

Comment: No signage or instructions were posted other than a map and the covid protocols

Comment: How can a temp card get these permissions?  Did you alter its credentials in the system?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Why couldn't a temp card have these permissions? And why wouldn't a temp card have permissions suitable to who it was assigned to?

Comment: @Anthony So why didn't you just bring the badge with you and returned it the day after?

Comment: @greg to avoid exactly this happening.

Comment: In addition to the advice others gave, I would suggest installing a drop box that cannot be accessed without a key for after hours dropoffs of badges.  That would help prevent this kind of problem in the future.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere That sounds like an answer. Could you put it in the answer box, please? (Answering in comments is bad.)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Typically the level of trust scales with the level of responsibility. It's clear that the OP needs more training to be able to handle a pass with boosted security (temp or not).

Comment: Can you update us on what happened. You unfortunately will probably be fired but they may acknowledge your mistake forgive you and hopefully let it go.

Comment: Something that I haven't seen mentioned elsewhere is that doing your own research into who had the pass and what they did could potentially have been a foolish mistake in itself. Depending on how thoroughly the systems you accessed are audited, there's a chance that it might appear that you were trying to cover your tracks after having been 'found out'. In general, for something like this do nothing relating to the accusation without express permission from the people investigating you.

Comment: Purely as a matter of interest - what's done about the unauthorised picking up and usage by the other person?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave, not at all. I treated the incident as a regular security incident because it is. These are standard mitigating measures expected of any security professional in cases when access credentials could have been misused. By no means is it covering up, but threat mitigation

Comment: @Anthony That's not the problem.  It's called recusing yourself from the investigation because it's a conflict of interest.

Comment: Having read the update wrt consequences: congrats @Anthony and best wishes going forward.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

First, take the blame. Explain **exactly** what you did wrong. Explain how stupid it was for you to do that. If you start off by saying that the accusation is false, then they won't even listen to what you have to say afterward (even if what you say is technically correct).

Send out that email now. Do not wait. Even if you figured out that the server room wasn't compromised, they still need to know the exact details of what happened. But please, don't start off by saying that you were "wrongly accused". In my personal opinion, what you did was actually worse, security-wise, than lending out your badge to someone else.

In your case, by leaving your badge in an unsecured location, you essentially gave your badge to a perfect stranger (that at the time at least, you didn't even know the identity of). And objectively, that is actually worse than lending out your badge to a trusted individual (although both options are really bad either way).

So explain what you did, but don't try to use it as an excuse. If it starts sounding like an excuse, then an argument will ensue, and if an argument ensues, it's not going to go your way, for the reasons I've already outlined in my previous paragraph.

Also, there is nothing more infuriating than talking to someone who tries to prove you wrong over a small inconsequential technicality. On one hand, it's like the person you're speaking to can't even seem to see the forest from the trees. But on the other hand, it's like that person is trying to prove you wrong, in a futile attempt to challenge you and get power over you.

And yes, depending on the type of employer you working for, you could be fired over the security incident itself. But in my opinion, arguing this minor point now, that's the surest and quickest way to get yourself fired, even if they had no intention to fire you in the first place.

> I also see a system weakness in that expectations are unclear in
> return of badges during non working hours. Should this issue be raised
> when I respond?

No, you can raise this issue later, if you see that the signage/process has not changed at the reception. Raising it now will send the wrong message.

Comment: I guess he didn't just leave the access card openly on a reception desk. This would be equivalent to leaving your house keys on the porch when you leave for work. Receptions typically have a sealed container for return of temporary access cards when reception is not staffed (at least that's how it works where I work).

Comment: "If you start off by saying that the accusation is false, then they won't even listen..." - avoiding clearly and explicitly denying a false accusation is a good way to make it seem like the accusation is actually true and you're trying to dance around the issue to put you in a better position if evidence comes out that supports the accusation.

Comment: @Alderath "I guess he didn't just leave the access card openly ... Receptions typically have a sealed container" - if OP put the card in a sealed container, then the other person wouldn't easily have been able to take the card, this would be a much bigger security issue that OP doesn't have much to do with, OP would've presumably been following the card return policy and the question overall wouldn't make that much sense.

Comment: It's useful to say how you will prevent a similar problem from happening again. Plan A is obviously don't forget your badge again. But if you do, if the company has a standard policy on what to do if reception is unavailable, learn that and follow it. If not, make sure that comes up. "In the future, I won't forget my own badge, but I will make a point of learning and following company policy as to securing and returning temporary badges when reception is unavailable." If such a policy really doesn't exist, this will hopefully make folks realize and correct the issue more systemically.

Comment: @kojiro The OP is a lead in the cybersecurity division, I would imagine part of their role is to help determine these policies. It sounds like a policy the OP would write is: "Just leave the pass on the reception desk".

Comment: @Alderath, no drop box or secured storage. Badges were stored in locked drawers for which I did not have the key. Only reception and facilities folks do

Comment: @GregoryCurrie hah, I'm guessing not after this incident, but IMO it's a crucial indicator of the company's culture how they react to OP if OP responds with a mature apology and a mitigation strategy.

Comment: @kojiro I think the mitigation strategy is to fire security professionals that don't understand security.

Comment: ".... can be reason for summary dismissal"--but they haven't fired you yet, which implies that somebody thinks you are a good employee, and are worth saving. So I agree with the suggestion that you apologize and do whatever is needed to move on from the incident. Regard it as a learning experience.

Answer (score 50):

You DID hand your badge to another person, whether you intended to or not.

How that person got access to your badge is irrelevant, unless they stole it from your body or otherwise forced you to hand it over without them being authorised to do so.

Live up to your error, admit it, and accept the consequences. You can only hope it's not something you will get fired over, though in my experience (which is based on reading the rules in quite a few companies, never breaking them) is that a first offense will likely cause a negative mark on your performance review and possibly temporary revocation of privileges (meaning you won't be able to enter secured areas alone for a while).

You made a (stupid) mistake, admit it and don't try to hide the fact. Worse, you hiding the fact as long as you did already may well be taken far worse than you making the mistake in the first place.

Comment: Your first sentence states a literally different error than the one that happened.

Comment: @donjuedo no, by leaving it unattended he lost control over it so anyone could take it. That's the same as giving it to a random person.

Comment: yes, he lost control -- he allowed control to pass to someone else (really bad), but merriam-webster does not support your definition.  That's all I'm saying here.

Comment: I think when it comes to security, it is useful to think of things in these terms. You should assume by leaving you pass lying around, you ARE giving it to a bad actor. From a legal standpoint the distinction does matter however.

Comment: I have to disagree with the first sentence: there is a large difference between _actively_ doing something and allowing something to happen _out of neglicience_. What can be said is that he _allowed the possibility_ of another person getting his badge, he did not take _enough pre-cautionary measures_ to prevent this from happening. But he did NOT hand it to another person. It _could_ have been that no one took it and the receptionist would have taken it in the morning. How would the first sentence read in this case? Explaining _OPs_ actions cannot be connected to the outcome.

Comment: @Mayou36 there is no difference as to the resulting consequences for security. And that's all that matters here.

Comment: @Mayou36 what OP did is WORSE than loaning his badge to a fellow employee.

Comment: @Kevin, maybe. And maybe less. Depends a lot on the environment you're in. Not everyone abuses things, especially in such a highly protected environment. Honestly, I would clearly not use the badge but simply keep and return it (because I know that they will find me, cameras, etc.) What would I do with it? A crime in the company I work? Just because there is the opportunity to do so? No. I am actually surprised that someone took the card and used it. Remember, this is not the key to a box with cash in a store with employes that barely make it over the months

Comment: @Mayou36 No, you might not because you work there.  What about a delivery guy that walked in and saw it?  Random person that walked in to ask for directions? Just leaving a badge with elevated security permissions at the reception desk is just mind-boggling stupid

Comment: @Kevin, yes, what about them? It's a badge laying around. Will a random delivery guy pick that up? (just to get fired a few days later because he is on cameras...) And then "break" into the security systems? Highly unlikely. And it was on a weekend during non-working hours. No random person, no delivery guy walks in. I cannot think of a real example that would cause harm (except of rather unlikely events that STILL could happen oc). But maybe you can name a (realistic) scenario?

Comment: @Mayou36 I'm just baffled at your response.  First off, it wasn't on the weekend.  he said he left it when he left work on MONDAY.  Second, any number of people could have gotten ahold of it.  Cleaning crew, someone who slipped in with the cleaning crew, Bob's girlfriend who came inside with him because he forgot his wallet and the office was on the way to dinner, etc.  By your logic, might as well not have security badges at all because nobody will do anything because they'll get caught on camera.

Comment: @Kevin I misremembered indeed, it was Monday but after working hours. To cut the discussion short: why? Why would anyone take it? Would you? What can you do with it? And no, security has many layers. You need a badge to make it _harder_ but not because _everyone_ that somehow would get the opportunity to go in would go in. There are cameras around. Taking the card and using it is clearly an (easy traceable) crime. My argument is that it's not like dropping a penny: just because it lays there doesn't mean that someone would just pick it up. All you can do with it is criminal acts.

Comment: @Mayou, if my card had non elevated access, you may be right. However, I have privileged access and access to areas other non security folks do not such as server rooms, networking closets etc.

Comment: @Mayou36 "All you can do with it is criminal acts."  I have no words

Comment: "just because it lays there doesn't mean that someone would just pick it up. All you can do with it is criminal acts." - That's kinda WHY it's worse.

Comment: Yes. Would you pick it up and do a security breach in a room with cameras? The point is clearly the comparison with "handing it to someone". If OP gives it to someone, then the criminal energy needed to commit a crime (which it is in both cases, laying around or having it handed over) is smaller. Because OP somewhat legitimates it by handing it over. That is different from just picking up a card (which you in general are NOT supposed to do). Crimes can happen in both cases. But picking it up requires a criminal step more.

Answer (score 27):

You're in trouble, and it's in your best interests to clear things up *now*.

There are 2 points that you need to address *in your first response*:

1. This was an *accident*, you did not lend your badge, you left it in an insecure area.
2. The lack of due procedure to return temporary badges may lead to further such accidents.

I disagree with answers advising to just be "passive" about it; clarifying the intent is primordial, in my own view, as there is a massive difference between *consciously* breaking the rules and *accidentally* breaking the rules -- even if in this case the accident may have worst consequences.

The difficulty is in finding the right phrasing. You *do* need to take responsibility, and you *do not* want to appear to be making excuses or to appear to be shifting the blame.

Still, despite the difficulty, it's in your best interest to address the above 2 points.

Hence I would suggest a response in 5 parts:

1. Clarify your *intent*: you did *not* intentionally lend your badge to another, you made the mistake of leaving your badge in an insecure area instead.
2. Own it up. It was a mistake. Apologize, promise not to do it again, etc... Make it sincere, and not over long.
3. Show your recovery actions. As soon as you were pointed your mistake, you took explicit steps to ensure that no unauthorized access occurred from it.
4. Suggest improvements to the temporary-badge return procedure in the case of absence of authorized personnel at reception. The locked drop-box is a really nifty idea, the other is clarifying that should the drop-box be open the company would rather employees keep the temporary-badge with them until it can securely be returned.
5. Don't end on the suggestion -- it could be perceived as blame-shifting -- and instead put a one-liner reiterating that you own up to your mistake and will endeavor to ensure that it won't happen again.

These 5 parts contain the 2 important points -- clarification and concrete suggestion -- while ensuring that people do see you taking responsibility for your mistake, and driving the company forward.

I hope for you that your company favors blameless post-mortem to the hot potato game, and showing that you are reactive (reacting upon being notified) and proactive (taking steps to handle the immediate threats, and being thoughtful about systematically preventing re-occurrences rather than hoping) will hopefully help fixing the dent in your credibility.

Comment: I would end with "it's funny, I used to be judgmental when users made security mistakes, now I can see how easy it is to have a lapse".

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: Not sure about the "funny", may not strike the right mood.

Answer (score 16):

> How do I minimize damage as a result of the false accusation?

Explain that this was poor judgment on your part, that you understand the potential ramifications and consequences, and that it won't happen again.

> I also see a system weakness in that expectations are unclear in
> return of badges during non working hours. Should this issue be raised
> when I respond?

You should address this issue in your response, as it's related to why you did what you did. Ask what the policy is in this scenario and ask that it be published with the rest of the guidelines and policies.

Comment: If as seems likely the issue is that the company doesn't have a process for returning temporary badges after hours, I'll suggest proposing what my previous employer did.  There was a locked dropbox for temp badges at the reception desk, on your way out you dropped your temp badge into the box and it was processed the next morning.  Also our temp badges didn't have access into the most secure parts of the building; part of the price you had to pay for forgetting your badge was the embarrassment of having to ask coworkers to open some doors for you.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight I would just add to your comment, if an employee goes to use the dropbox and they realize it was left unlocked, an employee should still have enough common sense to say: "I better take this home" rather than shrug and go: "Well, I'm following the policy" and simply drop it in.

Comment: @Dan Fiddling, correct. Policy addressing the return of the temp badges is missing, which led to this incident as otherwise I would have followed it

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight in some/most/all companies, allowing someone through a secured door behind you (called "tailgating") is also _a violation of security policy_. 
While it's commonly ignored, asking a coworker to let you into a secured area won't cover you. I worked at one place where we had no conference room on our side of a door, so while 15-20 of us would troop through the held open door, each of us had to swipe our badge "to be on the safe side"...

Comment: @FreeMan I'm not saying it was the best of policies, but was how things worked there.  They drew a policy distinction between escorting (explicitly letting someone in) and tailgating (doing so surreptitiously); IIRC anyone escorted had to sign a visitors log even if they normally had badge access (not 100% sure after >5 years).  Temp badges couldn't easily be customized per user, and came in two types depending on if someone had access to the main secure area or not.  They couldn't get you into any project lab spaces or the (mostly unused in my building) communications/server rooms IT had.

Comment: Just pointing out, @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight, that "ask coworkers to open some doors for you" is frequently a policy violation in and of itself and _could_ have gotten both the OP and the coworker into (possibly more) trouble. I agree that the OPs company definitely needs a (better) policy on after-hours temp badge return.

Answer (score 10):

Let's face it. You've made a bad mistake, which is completely unreasonable for someone in your position to make. If you are not fired, it's likely the company has significant issues that need to be addressed around permissible standards of behaviour, and it's likely that there needs to be policy changes so mistakes like this in the future are met with terminations.

You should get on the front foot and explain exactly what happened, how your behaviour was fundamentally flawed, and the potential remedies that they could take (excluding firing you.)

Because you are a lead in the cybersecurity division, you are able to see the potential remedies for such a situation. You should suggest that you undertake the most onerous of trainings available. And you should be very eager to undertake them.

Depending on employment law in your jurisdiction, if you are fired, you may be better off asking if you can resign rather than be fired.

And, as a side note, you justification for leaving your pass in reception doesn't make a lot of sense. You should have absolutely taken the pass home. Without justifying your own behaviour, you could suggest improvements to policy to ensure no other employee is unsure what to do in such a situation.

Comment: The "if you are not fired" sentence comes across as rude and opinionated.  It doesn't look to be obviously relevant to the rest of the answer; if you removed it the remaining answer would be great.

Comment: "If you are not fired, it's likely the company has significant issues that need to be addressed around permissible standards of behaviour" - well then, I hope every company I ever work for has "significant issues that need to be addressed". I personally much prefer for years of good work tp be able to counteract (to a reasonable degree) someone making one mistake due to bad judgement involving unclear policies that really should be clearly defined, when that mistake didn't appear to result in any negative consequences for the company or anyone else.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I think we can agree that there are various degrees of mistakes. To leave a pass with elevated security permissions, in a place that is public facing, is a pretty serious transgression in my book. The OP's role in the organisation suggests they deserve a higher degree of scrutiny. In my mind, they are either blindingly incompetent, or acting with malice.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie If harm was done, then I'd be more inclined to fire them in case there was malice (and to make the severity of such mistakes clear to others). If no harm was done, their track record is otherwise spotless and they realise it was a big mistake, then it seems likely to be in the best interest of the company to give them a second chance instead of taking a chance on someone new (although working in security makes it a bigger mistake). Some companies have very strict policies to not remove things from the premises and to return things on time, so taking it home isn't so obvious.

Comment: @NotThatGuy The thing is, I don't think the outcome really matters. I think someone who makes a minor error leading to a very bad outcome shouldn't be "punished" more than someone that makes an extremely bad error which, due to luck, doesn't have a bad outcome.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie The outcome matters as far as malice is concerned. If the person who misused the badge didn't do anything bad with it, then malice on the part of OP is unlikely (if they tried to do something bad, but failed, then it's a bit more of a gray area). Beyond that, treating OP differently based on the outcome is a bit "unfair", but it can make sense in terms of the perception of other employees, the public, shareholders, etc.: if something bad happened and there were no consequences for those who caused it, it can make it seem like the company doesn't care all that much.

Comment: I really don't think employers should throw their employees under a bid to satisfy the mob, or to satisfy shareholders, etc. They should apply standards consistently according the behaviour itself.

Comment: @NotThatGuy, I think it is fair to treat OP based on their position though. If OP were an intern or low-level employee that didn't know any better, this could be written off as a teachable moment. But a 9-year veteran of the company, and lead in the security department no less, should really, really know better. Malice or not, at their level this kind of mistake calls everything into question.

Answer (score 8):

> I left my temp badge at reception

Great, now prove to me that this was not a malice plot; aka, prove a negative. Good luck...

---

> Even worse, due to role in security division, expectations to follow policy is higher than for non info security folks

No kidding...

---

> How do I minimize damage as a result of the false accusation?

The accusation seems legitimate, actually.

Have you had a chance to explain yourself or is this accusation a "one-way street"?

---

> I also see a system weakness in that expectations are unclear in return of badges during non working hours. Should this issue be raised when I respond?

Are you trying to get immediately terminated and escorted by security?

Might as well try to accuse the front desk people checking in badges as being the true system weakness. Hint, don't do this.

The only weakness is that the expectations were unclear to **you**; this part you can mention and request clarification. If they cannot readily produce clarification then it will become apparent that there could be some missing instruction but as a 9-year cybersecurity employee you are expected to use sound judgement at all times.

Comment: This answer is nonsense.  Guess what... humans are fallible.  Any reasonable security practice considers this fact and takes it into account.  The OP here is trying to correct the problem and mitigate it from happening again.  Any reasonable management will be wanting to do the same thing, and OP has part of the solution.  Of course it should be included in this e-mail.  I don't know what company you work for, but I sure hope you're not in management.  Attitudes like yours are a great way to get people to hide things... which I assure you is not good for security.

Comment: @user1234567890abcdef Agreed, hence the "Have you had a chance to explain yourself or is this accusation a "one-way street"?" line. If nobody had used the badge then OP would have dodged a bullet but the fact of the matter is that someone else did use it. As an admin, it's akin to leaving my SSH screen open while I go grab a coffee. There's no hard and fast rules set forth by my supervisor but this would fall under "unsound judgement", no?

Comment: I agree with @MonkeyZeus. If a company is large enough to have security cards, then their security admins are undoubtedly expected to have a fairly thorough understanding of best security practices. Leaving your security card on your own desk because you were busy and forgot is one thing... leaving it on a public reception desk because "Eh, I don't know what to do with this" is totally different. From a manager or HR perspective, the first is being fallible whereas the latter is being incompetent.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would take the middle ground between these answers.  simply respond with the facts.  No 'apologies' or 'defense' just "I did not give the badge to {other employee.} I left the badge in reception as I left on Monday night at {time},  I can only assume someone re-issued the badge without resetting the owner'

Simple, gets your side of the story in, and doesn't admit any blame.

Comment: I would also add that you've checked the access logs and camera footage and there was no unauthorized access.

Comment: Not admitting blame in this case is the wrong thing to do and will have a real possibility of indicating the complacency is continuing.

Comment: One key question the company would likely ask themselves is whether this employee is a security risk for the company (and, if they are, fire them). If the employee doesn't acknowledge that what they did was wrong, then the answer to that question is much more likely to be "yes".

Comment: @StackerLee, a judgment that is wrong in hindsight does not necessarily amount to "blame". An essential part of the behavioural routine, the attendance of the security desk to handle and cancel returned passes, had already failed. Tired workers dealing with unfamiliar situations will make a variety of judgments, not necessarily the most desirable ones.

Comment: @Steve a serious error was made, regardless of context. It needs acknowledging. To decline to do so risks being read as either arrogance, complacency or denial, and if so, each will count against OP in HRs assessment.

Comment: @StackerLee I think you're right,  but I think it goes in order 1. I did not do the thing you're accusing me of specifically (lend the badge to someone else, this is the specifically sackable offense, right?. and OP didn't do it) 2. I did leave it in reception, which in hindsight may not have been the best thing to do, but I did this because at the time I thought it was better than taking the temporary pass off-site.

Comment: @StackerLee, it was erroneous in the sense that it cannot be endorsed in highsight and having seen the outcome develop, and it would not be how he would handle future situations. He can acknowledge that. But he does not need to acknowledge "blame" in the sense of misconduct or dereliction, or in the sense of the judgment being unreasonable at the time that he made it (which was without the new knowledge and multi-party scrutiny). Even levelling an accusation of that - without more - is unreasonable of HR. Not all wrong or undesirable actions are blameworthy.

Answer (score -13):

### Do not admit anything, defend yourself, it is not your fault

First of all, you had to work late at night. Unless you started original mess, you basically had to clean up for someone else mistakes, and is no wonder you forgot your own badge. Situation is akin to calling doctor in an emergency from his home, and than complaining because he did not bring his white coat.

Then you had to do what you did with temporary badge. Again, it is not your fault reception was not working. Nor it was the fault of people working there, it is an organizational flaw. Also, you are not to blame if someone stole temporary badge from reception, or if guys working at reception did not check access rights of said badge before handing it to someone else.

Finally, no harm has been done. Person who got the badge after you did not do any damage.

My personal hunch is that **somebody tries to scapegoat you** for the original incident and for the all organizational flaws with reception, system of badge access. As they say that attack is a best defense, they are now attacking you for something that was their job to do. I would **retaliate in kind**, would gather evidence of their wrongdoing and present them to higher management if they insist on these accusations. In the whole affair your only mistakes was not bringing your badge from home, which is minor, especially if you were being called in an emergency late at night.

Also, depending on your locale and employment laws (hiring and firing at will or not) you could talk with some lawyer about your options. In any case, do not admit anything, do not sign anything, do not voluntarily leave your job unless you find some other position.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132747/discussion-on-answer-by-rs-29-wrongfully-accused-of-lending-my-security-badge-to).